# Pandas add grouping to each column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset that has one line per user per week that records whether or not the user has registered along with values of certain metrics:

```
cols = ["Worker ID", "Registered", "Week Ending", "Metric Value"]
rows = [
    ['A', True, '2022-08-06', 2],
    ['B', False, '2022-08-06', 3],
    ['C', False, '2022-08-06', 4],
    ['A', True, '2022-08-13', 3],
    ['B', False, '2022-08-13', 2],
    ['C', True, '2022-08-13', 5]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data = rows)
```

I need to group by `Week Ending` and `Registered` and aggregate by number of unique worker ids and sum of the metrics. Normally this would be like this:

```
df.groupby(["Week Ending", "Registered"]).agg({'Worker ID': pd.Series.nunique, "Metric Value": sum})
```

This provides groupings as rows. I would like to have the registration group be along columns, something like:

| Week Ending Date | Worker ID Reg True | Worker ID Reg False | Metric Value Reg True | Metric Value Reg False |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-06 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 7 |
| 2022-08-13 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 2 |

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unstack` so:

```
df.groupby(["Week Ending", "Registered"]).agg({'Worker ID': pd.Series.nunique, "Metric Value": sum}).unstack()
```